How to visually overlap a button over a button in Bootstrap v5.3.2?
I have an accordion and I want to have some additional stuff within the accordion's header. Specifically, I want 2 spans aligned to the left, stacked on top of one another. I've accomplished this as seen below.
However, I also want to have a button-like mechanism aligned to the right of the accordion header. I need it to be clickable image. While I was able to accomplish what I need visually, having a child button obviously triggers a parent button-- and I know that it is not valid HTML to embed a button. So, could anyone help me made the image button visually overlapping, rather than actually being inside the accordion button?
<div class="accordion border-0 accordion-borderless">
                <div class="accordion-item border-0 pt-2 cs-bg-gray cs-text-gray">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header border border-0 rounded m-0 cs-bg-gray pb-2" id="heading"> 
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion{{.Id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion{{.ID}}">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                <div class="d-block w-100">
                                    <span class="d-block">
                                        Top span
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="cs-text-black d-block opacity-50 w-100" style="font-size: 14px; padding-top: 2px;">
                                        Bottom span
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex">
                                    <!-- HERE -->
                                    <img class="btn" src="/static/copyIcon.png" style="width: 50px;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </button>                                             
                    </h2> 
               </div>
</div>
...
               

I've tried putting the button / image outside of the accordion header and border, and then manually setting the display to absolute and using different padding/margins, but it doesn't quite turn out correct.
Image

Including a sample image might help. But... are you sure this is the best UI-feasible way to do such a thing? Have you considered using the "badge" element? Or do you need to be using Javascript to swap out one button for another (text, visibility, etc.)

Sorry about that! I've included an image. The "badge" element however is non-interactive, while I want my image to be interactive

@WillBelden ^^^

"I've tried putting the button / image outside of the accordion header and border" - the button element is what triggers the functionality, based on the data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target attributes. So there is not need to move everything out of the header (that's likely going to cause even more problems with styling) - just put the image after the button. Then position it absolute, and add some padding-right on the button content, so that the image won't overlay the text. (The text might break into more than two lines on narrow screens then, but there's hardly an alternative to that.)
